# Uncaught syntax error:

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have the following code: which returns uncaught syntax error :. If I remove the dataType i get no errors but i also get no data?

```
function myfunc() {
    var value = $("#firstselect").val();
    $.get("contactlist.php", 
          {SEARCH_PARAM: value },
          dataType: "json",
          function(data) {
              var options = '<option value="">Select one...</option>';
              for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  options += '<option value="' + data[i].id +'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';
              }
              $("#secondselect").html(options);
          }
    );
}
```

Comment: That means your server isn't returning JSON.

Comment: Did you tried `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.get()`?

Comment: have you tried adding  contextType:'text/plain; charset=UTF-8' to the request.

Comment: You can't use `dataType: 'json'` as an argument to the `get` function.  It's your syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your success function needs to come before data type, and the data type should just be a string literal, not a named value:

```
function myfunc() {
  var value = $("#firstselect").val();
   $.get("contactlist.php", 
   {SEARCH_PARAM: value },
    function(data) {
      var options = '<option value="">Select one...</option>';
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + data[i].id +'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';
      }
      $("#secondselect").html(options);
    },
   "json"
  );

}
```

Comment: The OP was trying to mix `$.ajax()` and `$.get()` with the way he/she was using key/value pairs as arguments. Make sure to read documentation on a function prior to use...

Comment: Thanks Brian! I agree I should read the documentation...what a dummy I am...:-)

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token } with jquery 1.7.1 Any ideas?

Comment: @JamesFerguson Can you post your code? It seems like you probably just have an unmatched } somewhere.

Comment: I got it, I had broken some code in a separate location. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have the parameters in a wrong order.
DataType has to be the last

try:

```
function myfunc() {
var value = $("#firstselect").val();
$.get("contactlist.php", 
      {SEARCH_PARAM: value }
      function(data) {
          var options = '<option value="">Select one...</option>';
          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              options += '<option value="' + data[i].id +'">'+data[i].name+'</option>';
          }
          $("#secondselect").html(options);
      },
      "json"
);
}
```